# how to sort javascript associate array by in-depth value

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an associative array i'm trying to sort it by its score values.

This is the array i'm trying to sort:
`{"0":{"score": 30 }, "1":{"score": 10 }, "2": {"score": 20 }}`

This is the result i am expecting:
`{"0":{"score": 10 }, "1":{"score": 20 }, "2": {"score": 30 }}`

As you can see, the expected result has been sorted by ascending "score". Thank you for the help

I am almost beginner with javascript, do you know whether there is a native javascript function to do this? or should I code my own solution with loops? I don't use jquery or another library, just pure vanilla javascript

Comment: Look into `array.prototype.sort` on mdn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First your JSON is not an array, After fixing this:

you can do this

```
var somthing = [{"score": 30 }, {"score": 10 }, {"score": 20 }];
somthing.sort(function(a, b){return a.score - b.score;});
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your starting thing is an object, not an array and you want to keep keys of the sort order... you'll have to do it manually...

```js
var startObj = {"0": {"score": 30}, "1": {"score": 10}, "2": {"score": 20}};
var finalObj = {};

console.log('Start Object = ' + JSON.stringify(startObj));

var startValues = Object.values(startObj);
startValues.sort((a, b) => {
  return (a.score - b.score);
});

startValues.forEach((valueObj, index) => {
  finalObj[index] = valueObj;
});

console.log('Final Object = ' + JSON.stringify(finalObj));
```